# Rails scope with complex SQL Statement including OR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, scopes, pundit

I'm working on a small Rails project right now. I'm using Pundit for authorization of controller actions and stuff. The job right now is to use Pundit for the index action and use Pundit's `policy_scope` in my controller to get the Projects a user can see.

There are 3 ways a user should be able to see a project:
- He's the owner
- He was invited
- The project is public

I've tried several solutions right now but ended up doing the following:

```
scope :public_or_involved, -> (user) { 
  joins('LEFT JOIN invitations ON invitations.project_id = projects.id').
  where('projects.is_public = TRUE OR projects.owner_id = ? OR invitations.reciever_id = ?', user.id, user.id) 
}
```

This is the only way I got something like a "public_or_involved" to work with the following pundit scope in project_policy.rb:

```
class Scope
  attr_reader :user, :scope

  def initialize(user, scope)
    @user = user
    @scope = scope
  end

  def resolve
    scope.public_or_involved(user)
  end
end
```

So my Question, finally:

**Is there an elegant way of doing what I'm doing now?**
It feels ugly and not rails-like!

Answer (score 0):

Caveat, I don't know pundit (I prefer the simpler DSL approach of [acl9](https://github.com/be9/acl9)), so I'm only really converting your query for you, you can usually get Rails to give you a `LEFT JOIN` with `includes()`, and you can use this little trick to get a neater `OR`:

```
scope :public_or_involved,
  -> (user) { includes(:invitations).where(
    where( is_public: true, owner_id: user.id, invitations: { receiver_id: user.id } ).where_values.reduce(&:or)
  )}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Does not work as expected. This produces `SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE (("projects"."owner_id" = $1 OR "projects"."is_public" = 't') OR "projects"."receiver_id" = 1633)` what then leads to an exception, since projects does not have a reciever. Error in console: `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column projects.receiver_id does not exist -> LINE 1: ...wner_id" = $1 OR "projects"."is_public" = 't') OR "projects"...`

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I didn't notice that the table was different for that one.  I've edited the query.

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, the solution you have now is the best one. You could use something like Arel, Squeel or MetaWhere to Ruby-fy your SQL strings, but those come with added complexity.

If this is meeting your requirements, I wouldn't worry too much about making it "more Rails-y."

Comment: This can't be it! Seriously this stuff is way to NOT DRY and not easy to read :(

Comment: I posit that it is easier to read than the alternatives, given the current state of Rails+ActiveRecord / Arel / Squeel / Metawhere, etc.